# Excel VBA: Type Mismatch explanation

Tags: vba, excel

I'm a newcomer to VBA so was hoping someone with more experience could please explain why I receive a

> Type Mismatch error

against the following:

```
Private Sub cbbWeek_Change()
txtWeekEnding = Application.VLookup(cbbWeek.Value, Worksheets("Formulas").Range("Q1:R53"), 2, False)
End Sub
```

I'm not sure if it's relevant but;

Column Q contains numbers from 1 (in cell Q1) to 52 (in cell Q52)
Column R contains dates formatted to dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: What is `cbbWeek.Value`?

Comment: The value from a combobox selection

Comment: @watsonman88 - what happens if you write `MsgBox (txtWeekEnding)` before the error line?

Comment: Does the value contained in that combobox match what is on column Q of Sheet Formulas? How did you declare txtWeekEnding, as date?

Comment: @Vityata - Blank box as it hasn't been assigned a value yet

Comment: @watsonmann - this is where the problem is exactly! :)

Comment: @Xabier Yes it does. I haven't declared it as a date specifically, I assumed it would just take the text of the cell I've referenced in the formula, ignoring any formatting?

Comment: @Vitaya - so I should initialize the text box with something before using it in the code?

Comment: @watsonman88 - I would use some kind of a check. In general `vlookup` returns always an error, if it does not find what it is searching for.

Comment: That has indeed solved the issue but now produces a different error; 1004, Unable to get the VLookup property of the WorksheetFunction Class. Should I raise this in a new post?

Comment: @watsonman88 - see the answer. The `Not IsError` check will work fine.

Answer (score 3):

To see whether VLookup returns an error or not - assign the returned value to a variable. Check if the variable is an error, and if it is not an error - assign it to txtWeekending:

```
Private Sub TestMe()

    Dim checker         As Variant
    Dim txtWeekending   As Variant

    checker = Application.VLookup("vityata", Range("A1:C53"), 2, False)
    If Not IsError(checker) Then
        Debug.Print checker
        txtWeekending = checker
    Else
        Debug.Print checker
    End If

End Sub
```

[This is an article from CPearson, concerning the same problem](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/callingworksheetfunctionsinvba.aspx).

Comment: Amazing, works great. I also understand now why it was producing the error which is a bonus! Thanks

Comment: I think that [this](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/callingworksheetfunctionsinvba.aspx) is worth to mention.

Comment: @CommonSense - CPearson is always worth to mention, impressive that the solution there is quite the same :)